# Python RE Find a Specific Word In a Text Document

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find a specific word on a line inside a text document using regular expressions. I tried using the below code but it doesn't work properly.

```
import re
f1 = open('text.txt', 'r')
for line in f1:
    m = re.search('(.*)(?<=Dog)Food(.*)', line)
    m.group(0)
    print "Found it."
f1.close()
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0
ns\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.0\visualstudi
0, in exec_file
    exec(code_obj, global_variables)
  File "C:\Users\wsdev2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projec
TML Head Script\HTML_Head_Script.py", line 6, in <module>
    m.group(0)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` because the match has not been found.

`re.search()` will return `None` if there is no match, so you can do this:

```
import re
with open('text.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        m = re.search('(.*)(?<=Dog)Food(.*)', line)
        if m is not None:
            m.group(0)
            print "Found it."
            break # Break out of the loop
```

---

Edit: I've edited my answer with your code. Also, I've used `with/as` here, as it automatically closes the file afterwards (and it looks pretty cool :p)

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your program:

- `m` will be none if there is no match in that line, which is why your program crashes.
- Your code will only find the first match in the line, if it exists. You can use the [`re.finditer()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) instead to iterate over all matches.
- Using `.*` before and after a word will match that word when it appears in the middle of another word, such as `DogFooding`. This probably isn’t what you want. Instead, you can use the magical `\b` atom in your match, which the [`re` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) describes as

  > `\b`    Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word. A word is defined as a sequence of alphanumeric or underscore characters, so the end of a word is indicated by whitespace or a non-alphanumeric, non-underscore character…

  You’ll probably want to use the special [`r''` raw string syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) instead of manually doubling the backslash to escape it.
- Using `(.*)` to find what happens before and after the match makes it hard to use the regular expression, because there will be no non-overlapping matches, even if the word occurs multiple times. Instead, use the `match.start()` and `match.end()` methods to get the character positions of the matches. Python’s [match objects are documented online](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject).

Taking this into consideration, your code becomes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import re
f1 = open('text.txt', 'r')
line_number = 1
for line in f1:
    for m in re.finditer(r'\bDogFood\b', line):
        print "Found", m.group(0), "line", line_number, "at", m.start(), "-", m.end()
    line_number += 1
f1.close()
```

When run using this is `text.txt`:

```
This Food is good.
This DogFood is good.
DogFooding is great.
DogFood DogFood DogFood.
```

The program prints:

```
Found DogFood line 2 at 5 - 12
Found DogFood line 4 at 0 - 7
Found DogFood line 4 at 8 - 15
Found DogFood line 4 at 16 - 23
```